# rds has a lot of messages Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, rds

I faced with errors in RDS mysql 5.7 logs:

```
[Note] Aborted connection 239056 to db: 'db' user: 'prod' host: '172.54.8.641' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I reade alot of articls but I'm not able fixed my issue yet. Now I create new "Parameter groups" for rds with values:

```
wait_timeout - 28800
interactive_timeout - 28800
connect_timeout - 28800
max_allowed_packet - 1073741824
net_read_timeout - 20
net_write_timeout - 20
```

and absolutely nothing.
I held meeting with developers and saw code when I made shure that connections was closed after finish.

Comment: Without knowing more about your setup, it is hard to say. Is your RDS instance set up to communicate with the server you are trying to reach it from? Did you verify the security group settings and/or virtual network settings are correct to allow them to communicate over the proper port(s)?

Comment: My application is working on ec2 in same vpc and SG is allowed access. Application work, my tasks processed, but every time I get this messages - Abort connection. ec2 - t2.medium, rds - same type. A load is low.

Comment: I edded datadog APM monitoring for my application and I see thah every select to my rds generate message :Got an error reading communication packets:

Answer (score 4):

It was application mistake. Bad closed connections.

Comment: you could provide a bit more details on the language that you use to connect  to the RDS instance. What was the best way to handle the connections. Thanks

Comment: It was nodeJs. We used mysql lib. I investigate new code hove close connections by official doc. Then create simple script which do just select and launched with my code for close connections. And code by developer. Whith my code errors was absent.